# Jump to source android studio on windows not working

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Anyone experienced the "Jump to source" function when doing widget selection does nothing? Im on android studio 3.6.1, and windows 10. Meanwhile, using visual studio its all working fine, widget selected will lead straight to the code where it got rendered. Any potential root cause for this? or its an ongoing issue?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.116], locale en-MY)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.43.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

**EDIT** : The following is the screenshot of where to use the function;
[image]

The shortcut key is Ctrl + Down.

Comment: "Jump to source" meaning ctrl-leftClick? it works just fine

Comment: Hi, i have edited my question with a screenshot. The shortcut key is Ctrl Down.

Comment: Jump To Type Source seems fine though.

Comment: I also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

So apparently i found out why is it so. Hopefully this may help some of the people facing the same issue.

You just need to git clone your project with the following default directory where new projects are created which is;

C:\Users\$username\AndroidStudioProjects

and try to re-open your project again. All working as intended for my case. This is the default project location where your new flutter projects will be created.

Comment: it work in my case, thanks!